# How to use a service declared in a Custom Angular Library into other project

Tags: angular, service, angular-library

I am trying to re use a service implemented in a custom library into other projects, the problem is that I receive this error: 'ERROR Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context'. Can someone give me some light in the darkness please?

This is my code:

```
// Library

    * Library Service

    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ApiService {
    
      constructor(http: HttpClient) {}
      ...
    }

    * Library Module

    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { ApiService } from './services/api-utils.service';
    import { ApiComponent } from './api.component';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        ApiComponent
      ],
      imports: [ 
        CommonModule ,
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      exports: [
        ApiComponent,
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      providers: [
        ApiService
      ]
    })
    export class ApiModule {}

// Application

* App Service

    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { ApiModule } from 'api';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        ...
      ],
      imports: [ 
        CommonModule,
        ApiModule,
        ...
      ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Have you imported the service in the app module of your other project or how do you try to share the service?

Comment: The service I want to import implements the http calls to a backed, for this reason I have created a library and declared this service into it; because I have two fronted application that has in common the same backend so I thought is a nice way to save code. After installing the library into the other application projects, I have tried to inject the service (Api Service) directly in the constructor of a project service but I receive this error. But I have noticed that this error only appears when I try to inject the api service because this service contains a HttpClient dependency.

Comment: If I delete HttpClient dependency nothing appears and I can use the service into the projects. Furthermore I have read some post in which said that I have to import a LibraryModule to inject the services, but I have tried and nothings happens.

Comment: Have you imported the `HttpClientModule` in your second app module?

Comment: Or you can import the module from your first app directly into your second app, you may want to have a look at this one: https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

Comment: First I have added HttpClientModule to 'imports' array of <library>.module, also I have included in this module the Service in 'providers' array. In the application side I have imported directly the library module, and added inside 'imports' array of a module I want to use the library service (My application is divided into several modules to implement Lazy Load). So I have to import the HttpClientModule inside application module too?